# Scrolling GridView like PageView

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to make the GridView scroll like PageView. For example, as an iPhone desktop on which the tables of icons are scrolled. It is as if I put the GridView in the PageView. But it doesn't work that way. I also tried splitting the sheet into parts, it worked, but it doesn't work for me in the future.

Video example:
https://vimeo.com/641943434

Only when the PageView is scrolled to a new page, the GridView is repeated, but should show new icons

Comment: You want something like this? https://www.kindacode.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Flutter-Horizontal-GridView.mp4

Comment: @YasineRomdhane I added a video example

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so what you need is a GridView that scrolls horizontally instead of vertically.
You just make the Gridview as big as the screen, then set `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal`

```
GridView(
     scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
     children: [
               // Some widgets
     ],
),
```

Comment: No. Scrolling should be like a PageView with a stop on the page.

Comment: Just make a few pages with gridviews in it then.